# can I have a world where woman vs men in combat sports if they have superpowers?"

Tags: humans, worldbuilding-process, combat, sports, hand-to-hand-combat

I don't know why but people still have a push back against the women fighting men in fiction thing. Because it's not realistic some say. Because men are biologically stronger than women. Despite people being ok with smaller men fighting bigger men in fiction forever.

Action Heroes like John Wick and The Fast and The Furious characters. Are pretty much superhumans. But yet people still limit female characters to real-world human standards. But never give an opinion on men not following the same rules.

Smaller men can fight bigger men in movies. And one man can fight 100 men in movies. So far I haven't seen anybody complain about that.

In my world the fighters are superhuman. There are no weight limits or gender limits. Fighters who win fights are determined by who is more skilled, powerful, or who has better technique.

So the Female fighters can go toe to toe with the Male Fighters and win in my world. The same way the small guys can go toe to toe with the big guys and win in my world too.

So is it still a big issue to make women fight men in a superhuman combat sport?

Btw by Superhuman, I don't mean X Men or My Hero Academia. By Superhuman I mean Batman or Captain America.

Comment: Whether it is a big issue or not seems like a function of the cultural perceptions of your world. In other words you get to make be as big or little a deal as you want it to be.

Comment: In action movies, women fight men quite often, and they win quite often too. Problem is that audience of these movies are regular people who have regular perceptions about men fighting women. Which means that one big limitation is that a male hero can not physically fight women, even if they are villainous. For male villains and antiheroes there is generally no such limitation.

Comment: This seems much more like a question for Writers.SE.

Comment: Seriously, considering your question record and the way that you've written this one - indicating that you seemed to have learned nothing about what's on-topic here, please re-read the [help] requirements for on-topic questions. There is a severe limit which is built into the software of the site, if you carry-on as you are, you will definitely receive a question ban.

Comment: You need to clarify in what sense it is 'ok'. Are you talking about cultural factors (e.g. is it acceptable for men to fight women or vice versa)?[Please note, that this will not be a suitable question for WB.SE]  Or are you interested in the physical side of combat (e.g. would the fights be fair)? If you mean the latter you need to provide more information about combat system. For example, marksmanship competions [most likely do not need sex segregation to be fair](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11199-014-0436-y) but this is not the case for classic wrestling.

Comment: Doesn't matter how specific my question is. You guys will ways say it is vague or opinionated. Doesn't matter how detailed my post are. You guys will always turn my simple questions into something complex. Some simple like is it "ok" should've be vague. Especially if the question is simple. All im asking is it ok to have superhuman females fight superhuman males in a combat sport. That's it. That's all.

Comment: I VTC. The question is in this society highly opinionated. I would say yes they can, as superhumans have wildly different powers, negating any 'unfair' power difference from between men and women. But I'm sure we can find a large group of people who want segregation, for many of their own reasons.

Comment: But isn't every question opinionated though? How can I ask a question without it being opinionated? btw my fighters don't really have superpowers. I just call them superhumans because peak humans seem to not be a used term here. My fighters are low-level chi users at best.

Comment: Please understand we're not saying these things out of malice. But you're asking our direct opinion. A worldbuilding question would be "can I have a world where woman vs men in combat sports if they have superpowers?" It is a seemingly little change, but one asks about the possibilities and the other  about our opinion.

Comment: Gene Roddenberry put blacks and women on the bridges of the Federation's Flagships back in the 1960s during a time that neither would have even had a chance to be an officer of any sort.  He got away with it because his setting was different enough from our own reality that it made since.  As long as the culture of your setting has simply accepted men vs women as fair (or they do not care about fairness) for long enough, it really does not matter.

Comment: Because your setting allows super powers, your audience will not have trouble accepting this as different enough from our world to make since.  The real trap that these stories often run into is in the plot, not the setting. For example: Supergirl kicks boy alien butts day and night and no one questions her gender, but when she KOs Superman, a lot of people called BS because they are both Kryptonians, but Superman is the much more experienced and larger combatant.

Comment: Another note that may be of interest to you is that many states in the US have co-ed high-school wrestling leagues.  Many schools in my home state had 1-2 female wrestlers, and while it seemed "inappropriate" at first to most new wrestlers and parents there of, after you see it for a while it becomes very normalized.

Comment: You do not need our permission to write about anything. You do not need our permission to have women fight men, men fight women, or anything else. We will gladly help you develop a rule of your world (e.g., what the definition of "superpower" is in your world), but asking us for permission to write is always off-topic because the answer is always yes. (BTW, the superhero genre has had women kicking the snot out of men for almost 80 years. Have you done your research?)

Answer (score 3):

In the real world, *on average* women are smaller, weaker, and they have a different distribution of their muscle power. *Average* people don't compete in top championships, but there is a desire to see interesting fights of roughly evenly matched contenders.

- You could introduce [weight classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_class_(boxing)) similar to boxing to let *some* women fight *some* men. The problem is that in your setting, weight does not correlate with strength.
- You could have classic, gender-segregated tournaments (and world rankings) and also integrated tournaments. Statistically speaking, one would expect fewer women at the top ranks of the integrated tournaments, but who knows how super they are.
- Then there are the cultural issues mentioned by sphennings and Alexander in the comments. They apply both *in universe* and regarding your *target audience*.

  - In universe, some male heroes might be unwilling to hit a woman, even in sports. You could argue that that is their problem, and that they don't have to compete if they don't want to.
  - Out of universe, you might consider if you want to reinforce the existing cultural bias against men hitting women, or weaken it. Your story might not become the next big Hollywood movie, but you are doing your little piece to shape cultural expectations.
    Regarding the latter, you might show in your story (show, don't tell is always better) that male and female supers are in *a league of their own*, and that the cultural norms still apply outside that league.

Answer (score 1):

**You can**

Current segregation is based on that women and men are different in physical abilities. This is certainly correct in the top area of combat sports. You see the same with weight classes. The idea is to try to level the playing field, making sure the fighting is 'fair' and neither has a significant advantage over the other. With weight classes you can see this is already done with arbitrary classes. We could draw them up differently with more or less classes.

Your fighters have less problems with this. Women and men fighters are equally able. There is no need for segregation for fairness.

People might've problems ethically or morally, but that is down to the person. As you can have fair fights, segregation isn't needed.